# SliceStreamPlot3D or StreamPlot3D

Tags: plotting, vector, streams

I know that neither of the two functions listed in the title exist, but I basically replaced vector for stream to give you an idea of what I want. The most ideal would be `SliceStreamPlot3D`, as the `StreamPlot3D` would be harder to visualize. Instead of seeing the magnitude of the vector at each location, I want to see the flow, i.e. a line with an arrow giving a direction like in `StreamPlot`.

I do not have a function to give you as the function I am using describes the magnetic field of a non ideal object, asy example takes up three pages (it is an analytical solution; therefore composed of well defined functions).

Instead, say I have the function `f[y,-x,z]`, how can I show the `StreamPlot` say the $(x,y)$ plane at $z=0$ , another `StreamPlot` on the $y,z$ plane at $x=0$, and another `StreamPlot` on the $x,z$ plane at $y=0$?

For example I would like the following plot,

```
SliceVectorPlot3D[{y, -x, z}, "CenterPlanes", {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

but a `StreamPlot` instead of a `VectorPlot`.  Here are the `StreamPlots` that I would like to replace the `VectorPlots` in the `SliceVectorPlot3D`.

[image]

I can only put two pictures in (lack of reputation points), but you get what I'm wanting.  The other two would be

```
StreamPlot[{-x, z}, {x, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]    
StreamPlot[{y, z}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, -2, 2}]
```

Comment: "...the two functions...are real"?  *Real*?  What are you asking?

Comment: @David He means to say that he knows those two functions *do not exist yet*, but he would like help implementing them. Having said that, Josh, you need to provide something more to go on, I'm afraid. For instance, you don';t have to give us your function, but conjure up a simple example of application, and explain what you would like to see. Even better if you can make a mock-up of some kind.

Comment: It does not make sense to have a `SliceStreamPlot3D`, because the streamlines of the vector field will not stay on the slice planes in general.

Comment: @Josh I had seen your comment that you deleted. It seems I defined `f` to take a list of coordinates while your version takes `x, y, z` as separate arguments. Just change your definition and it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, my earlier first suggestion is exactly what `SliceVectorPlot3D` does, a function I was not aware of. Therefore, here is my suggestion how to convert 2d `StreamPlot`s and transfer the arrows created into 3d space

```
gr1 = Graphics3D[(First@
     StreamPlot[f[{x, y, 0}][[;; 2]], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
      StreamStyle -> ColorData[97, 2]]) /. 
   Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Tube[Append[#, 0] & /@ pts]]];
gr2 = Graphics3D[(First@
     StreamPlot[f[{0, y, z}][[{2, 3}]], {y, -3, 3}, {z, -3, 3}, 
      StreamStyle -> ColorData[97, 3]]) /. 
   Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Tube[Prepend[#, 0] & /@ pts]]];

Show[gr1, gr2, 
 Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[None], 
   FaceForm[{Opacity[0.3], ColorData[97, 2]}],
   Polygon[{{-3, -3, 0}, {-3, 3, 0}, {3, 3, 0}, {3, -3, 0}}],
   FaceForm[{Opacity[0.3], ColorData[97, 3]}],
   Polygon[{{0, -3, -3}, {0, -3, 3}, {0, 3, 3}, {0, 3, -3}}]

   }]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]