# Plotting a 2D slice of a 3D function

Tags: plotting

I'd like to plot `(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[z])^2` in a slice defined by `x+y+z=1`

I figured out similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5099148/419116) 5 years ago, but it was a bit involved, ie, needing 10 lines of Mathematica code. Is there anything in newer version that can make this simpler?

```
simplexPlot[func_, plotFunc_] := 
 Module[{A, B, p2r, r2p, p1, p2, p3, e, x1, x2, w, h, marg, y1, y2, 
   valid}, A = 
   Sqrt[2/3] {Cos[#], Sin[#], Sqrt[1/2]} & /@ 
     Table[Pi/2 + 2 Pi/3 + 2 k Pi/3, {k, 0, 2}] // Transpose;
  B = Inverse[A];
  (*map 3d probability vector into 2d vector*)
  p2r[{x_, y_, z_}] := Most[A.{x, y, z}];
  (*map 2d vector in 3d probability vector*)
  r2p[{u_, v_}] := B.{u, v, Sqrt[1/3]};
  (*Bounds to center the simplex*){p1, p2, p3} = Transpose[A];
  (*extra padding to use*)e = 1/20;
  x1 = First[p1] - e/2;
  x2 = First[p2] + e/2;
  w = x2 - x1;
  h = p3[[2]] - p2[[2]];
  marg = (w - h + e)/2;
  y1 = p2[[2]] - marg;
  y2 = p3[[2]] + marg;
  valid = 
   Function[{x, y}, Min[r2p[{x, y}]] >= 0 && Max[r2p[{x, y}]] <= 1];
  plotFunc[func @@ r2p[{x, y}], {x, x1, x2}, {y, y1, y2}, 
   RegionFunction -> valid]]
simplexPlot[(#1^2 + #2^2 + #3^2)^(1/2) &, ContourPlot]
```

[image]

Comment: There is [`SliceContourPlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SliceContourPlot3D.html), although it produces a [`Graphics3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics3D.html) object instead of a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics.html) object, e.g., ``SliceContourPlot3D[(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[z])^2, 
 x + y + z == 1, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]``

Comment: We had a similar, unfortunately really only similar, question lately [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/137809/187) that concerned creating slices of `VectorPlots`. I like the question, but I would be surprised if this wasn't already asked and probably answered. +1

Comment: Is this a toy example? Otherwise, why not just plotting `(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[1-x-y])^2`?

Comment: @Felix that gives a lopsided plot (doesn't look the same as picture)

Comment: Your picture shows `Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]`, which isn't the same as `(Sqrt[x] + Sqrt[y] + Sqrt[1-x-y])^2` as proposed in your first sentence. Anyways, I agree that it looks different, but to understand what you really want one has to reverse-engineer the code in your example. For instance, what are the axes in your plot?

Comment: The possible approaches raise and fall with the equation defining the slice you want to plot. Is it always a 2D plane inside 3D space or do you intend to cover curved shapes as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is quite straightforward.

First find the coordinate transformation from the 3D coordinates of the slice to a 2D coordinate system of our choice.

[image]

I will have the new x-axis running along the bottom edge of the triangle with origin at `{1/2, 1/2, 0}`. The new y-axis will of course run from this edge up to the vertex at the top. As such, I can map three points in 3D space to 3 points in our 2D space like so:

```
3D           2D
----------------------------
{1, 0, 0} -> {-1/Sqrt[2], 0}
{0, 1, 0} -> {+1/Sqrt[2], 0}
{0, 0, 1} -> { 0, Sqrt[3/2]}
```

A 3x2 scaling matrix plus a length-3 vector are sufficient to describe the coordinate transformation from 2D coordinates to 3D coordinates.

I will refer to the original 3D coordinates as `x0, y0, z0` and the new 2D coordinates as `x, y`.

Let's find the matrix:

```
kk = Array[k, 6];
mat = Partition[kk, 2];
bb = Array[b, 3];
source = {{-1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {1/Sqrt[2], 0}, {0, Sqrt[3/2]}};
target = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}};
eqs = Table[mat.source[[i]] + bb == target[[i]], {i, 3}];
```

So here `mat.{x,y} + bb` gets us the `{x0,y0,z0}` for a given `{x,y}` and `equs` simply are the three equations for each vertex of the triangular region in the figure above. Now we can solve:

```
sol = First@Solve[eqs, kk~Join~bb];
expr = mat.{x, y} + bb /. sol
```

`expr` are the 3D coordinates in terms of the 2D ones:

[image]

Now find the constraints on the values of `x` and `y` by requiring `{x0, y0, z0}` all to be positive:

```
reg = ImplicitRegion[Reduce[Thread[expr > 0]], {x, y}];
```

Finally find the value to be plotted:

```
val = Total[Sqrt[expr]]^2;
```

And plot it:

```
ContourPlot[val, {x, y} ∈ reg, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotPoints -> 50]
```

[image]